# tkinter.TclError: bad window path name

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from stock import getFruitStockInParalel
from tkscrolledframe import ScrolledFrame
#some other modules that aren't relevant to the class in question

class StockFrame(ScrolledFrame):
    BG = "#90A4AE"

    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        #Create variables
        self.lVisible = False
        self.blVisible = False

        self.cFruitLabels = list()
        self.lFruitLabels = list()
        self.blFruitLabels = list()

        self.cFruits = list()
        self.lFruits = list()
        self.blFruits = list()
        self.cFruits, self.lFruits, self.blFruits = getFruitStockInParalel()

        #Create Frame inside parent ScrolledFrame
        self.mainFrame = self.display_widget(tk.Frame, fit_width=True)
        self.mainFrame.config(borderwidth=3, background=self.BG, height=1500)
        self.mainFrame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.mainFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="stockframe")
        self.mainFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="stockframe")

        #Create and place Label that displays time till restock
        self.timeTillRestockLabel = tk.Label(self.mainFrame, text="", anchor=tk.W, font=("Segoe UI", 10), bg="white", relief="ridge", borderwidth=2, padx=5, pady=2)
        self.timeTillRestockLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, padx=6, columnspan=2, pady=5)

        #Create and place Buttons that toggle last and before last stock
        self.lButton = tk.Button(self.mainFrame, text="Toggle Last Stock", command=self.toggleLastStock, padx=100, bg="white")
        self.lButton.grid(row=100, columnspan=2, column=0, padx=7, pady=0, sticky=tk.W)

        self.blButton = tk.Button(self.mainFrame, text="Toggle Before Last Stock", command=self.toggleBlastStock, padx=100, bg="white")
        self.blButton.grid(row=102, columnspan=2, column=0, padx=7, pady=0, sticky=tk.W)

        #Create lFrame and blFrame
        self.lFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame, bg=self.BG)
        self.lFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="lframe")
        self.lFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="lframe")

        self.blFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame, bg=self.BG)
        self.blFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="blframe")
        self.blFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="blframe")

        #Start mainLoop
        self.mainLoop()


    def mainLoop(self):
        self.updateCurrentFruits()
        #self.updatelFrame()
        #self.updatelFrame()
        self.after(10*1000, self.mainLoop)


    def updateCurrentFruits(self):
        #Destroy previous fruit labels
        for fl in self.cFruitLabels: 
            fl.destroy()

        #Create new fruit labels and place them
        for fruit in self.cFruits:
            self.cFruitLabels.append(fruitLabel(self.mainFrame, fruit.name, usePrice=True))

        for i, fl in enumerate(self.cFruitLabels):
            fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), pady=(0,5))
    

    def toggleLastStock(self):
        if not self.lVisible:
            self.lVisible = True
            self.lFrame.grid(row=101, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        elif self.lVisible:
            self.lVisible = False
            self.lFrame.grid_forget()
        

    def toggleBlastStock(self):
        if not self.blVisible:
            self.blVisible = True
            self.blFrame.grid(row=103, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        elif self.blVisible:
            self.blVisible = False
            self.blFrame.grid_forget()


    def updatelFrame(self):
        #Destroy previous fruit labels in lFrame
        for fl in self.lFruitLabels: 
                fl.destroy()

        #Create new fruit labels and place them
        for fruit in self.lFruits:
            self.lFruitLabels.append(fruitLabel(self.lFrame, fruit.name, usePrice=True))

        for i, fl in enumerate(self.lFruitLabels):
            fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), padx=7, pady=(5,1))


    def updateblFrame(self):
        #Destroy previous fruit labels in blFrame
        for fl in self.blFruitLabels: 
            fl.destroy()

        #Create new fruit labels and place them
        for fruit in self.blFruits:
            self.blFruitLabels.append(fruitLabel(self.blFrame, fruit.name, usePrice=True))

        for i, fl in enumerate(self.blFruitLabels):
            fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), padx=7, pady=(5,1))

root = tk.Tk()
a = StockFrame(root, relief="solid", scrollbars="vertical", width=200)
a.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.W + tk.S)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.update_idletasks()
root.mainloop()
```

`fruitLabel` is a function that returns a Frame with a few things based on the fruitName. I have checked and it works perfectly but if it is relevant comment and I'll add the code for it

I created this class for a app I'm making and what I intend to happen is that there's an lFrame and a blFrame which have some fruitLabels in them and when I click the buttons it'll toggle the lFrame and blFrame's visibility respectively.
However, when I run the code I get this error

```
  File "c:\Users\Public\codg\bloxfruits\scripts\gui.py", line 244, in <module>
    a = StockFrame(root, relief="solid", scrollbars="vertical", width=200)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Public\codg\bloxfruits\scripts\gui.py", line 175, in __init__
    self.mainLoop()
  File "c:\Users\Public\codg\bloxfruits\scripts\gui.py", line 181, in mainLoop
    self.updatelFrame()
  File "c:\Users\Public\codg\bloxfruits\scripts\gui.py", line 228, in updatelFrame
    fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), padx=7, pady=(5,1))
  File "C:\Users\Tiago Charrão\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2564, in grid_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!stockframe.!canvas.!frame.!frame.!frame"
```

I've checked and the data returned by `getFruitStockInParalel` is correct

Also, it might be relevant to say that when I replace the mainLoop with just:

```
def mainLoop(self):
        self.updateCurrentFruits()
        self.after(10*1000, self.mainLoop)
```

It shows the fruitLabels for cFruits correctly when the loop runs the first time, but when it runs a second time I get a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tiago Charrão\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1962, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Tiago Charrão\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 861, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Public\codg\bloxfruits\scripts\gui.py", line 179, in mainLoop
    self.updateCurrentFruits()
  File "c:\Users\Public\codg\bloxfruits\scripts\gui.py", line 195, in updateCurrentFruits
    fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), pady=(0,5))
  File "C:\Users\Tiago Charrão\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2564, in grid_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!stockframe.!canvas.!frame.!frame3"
```

(Btw I'm only now learning how to do gui stuff with classes so if anything I did is out of convention or not good I'd apreciate the info thanks)

Comment: I realize some functions and classes aren't included in the answer but if you think they're relevant just comment and I'll add them

Comment: In several of your functions, you are destroying all of the current labels of a certain type, creating some new labels, and then calling `.grid()` on *ALL* of the labels - both the destroyed ones and the new ones.  You need to clear the old labels out of the list, as there is nothing further you can do with them after calling `.destroy()` on them.

Comment: So I should do something like self.cFruitLabels = list() when I destroy the labels?

Comment: That would work, although I'd personally use `self.cFruitLabels.clear()` rather than creating a new list.  (And the standard way of creating a new list is simply `[]`, rather than `list()`.)

Comment: Yeah that fixed it thanks
By the way while I have your attention do you think the way I'm doing things in a class is good? Like with the loop and stuff